# MVC MapRoute with username

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, maproute

I'm building a small MVC application. After a user logs in I want his/her route to display:

`www.appname.com/username/`

Underneath of course same action is called for each user e.g. `/home/index`. How do I write my `MapRoute` to achieve that and what other code(attributes) should I use?

Comment: What characters are authorized in a username? Do you allow a user to register on your site with username = Home/Index for example?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, Usernames will have no special characters. I'm building it mostly for learning purposes, so nothing overly complex, just want to have user to log in and see a custom url that could be shared with other people.

Answer (score 1):

Add this rout to your routes in `global.asax.cs` file

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            "RouteName", // Route name
            "FixedUrlSegment/{UserName}/{Controller}/{action}/{id}/", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "ControllerName", 
                  action = "ActionName",
                  id=UrlParameter.Optional
                }, 
        );
```

I think you should use a fixed segment as start-up point for your route to distinguish it from default or other routes

of course in log in action method you must redirect to that new route

```
return RedirectToRoutePermanent("RouteName", new { username = "UserName",
                                                   action = "Index", 
                                                   controller = "Home",
                                                   id="userId"
                                                 }
                                );
// remember id is not required for that route as mentioned in global file
```

this example will redirect your page to url

`www.appname.com/FixedUrlSegment/loggedusername/home/index/loggeduserid`